# Memory leak with Android app?

Tags: android, json, memory-leaks

I have a simple Android app that reads some JSON data from a php file on my local server. It's very simple and up until about an hour ago it was working fine. However, after a little break (I didn't even turn my PC off), it's suddenly struggling with what seems like a memory leak, although I'm no expert on the subject.

I'm not sure why all of a sudden this is happening, as I didn't change any code. But when I run the app my logcat slowly starts to fill with messages like this:

"GC_CONCURRENT freed, 910K, 53% free 3167K/6727K....."

The app eventually runs, but only after about 1-2 minutes of waiting. Anyway, I was wondering if someone could check my code or advise me what maybe causing this to happen.

```
public static JSONArray getJSONfromURL(String url) {

    // initialize
    InputStream is = null;
    JSONArray jArray = null;
    String result = "";

    // http post
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }

    // convert response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "utf-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jArray = new JSONArray(result);         
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return jArray;
}
```

The JSON data isn't very large at all.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: try to run your http call and json parsing in an async task

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm pretty new to android development, so i guess I have some reading to do. It just seems strange that this should start happening all of a sudden, when it was working absolutely fine.

Comment: Firstly try to use a separate thread for it or better is Async task. Secondly it's a better approach to use finally block and close the input stream there. Thirdly a memory leak might be some where else in your code so also give that a look as well...

Comment: How often do you call this method?

Comment: Just once. I've narrowed the problem down to the While((line = reader.readline() line. I think the 'line' string is too long maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            is, "utf-8"), 8);
```

You've allocated a buffer size of 8 bytes. That is very small. Unless you really know what you're doing, just use the default size with the alternative single-argument constructor:

```
public BufferedReader(Reader in)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I changed the 'While' loop to this and performance increased dramatically:

```
int len;
char[] chars = new char[4*1024];
while((len = reader.read(chars))>=0) {
sb.append(chars, 0, len);
}
```

It's still slower than I'd like, but at least I'm heading in the right direction. I'm going to work on it some more. Thanks everyone.